# variable global const "macros" in C++ and optimal design patterns

Tags: c++, design-patterns, mfc, constants, global

I inherited some 10 year old code I have to complete. The code is in MFC (C++).

There's a .h file where the custom data structures are written and some const variables are in there as Globals. Some of these are used for MS Office file extensions, of type CString, and are declared as _T(".doc"), _T(".xls"), etc.

Obviously these are dated and need to be updated to recognize the Office 2007 and later extensions. My first brilliant idea was to use const_cast to change the constant if needed, but found out later that's a no-no and resulted in undefined behavior (sometimes it would switch back to .doc).

I then decided to create a struct and have two structs inherit from it. I created a void method in the base struct to make it abstract but otherwise it does nothing. Here's the code:

```
struct eOfficeExtensions{

    const CString WORD_EXTENSION;
    const CString EXCEL_EXTENSION;
    const CString WORDPAD_EXTENSION;
    const INT EXTENSION2007;

    eOfficeExtensions(CString word, CString excel, CString wordpad, INT ver) : 
        WORD_EXTENSION(word), EXCEL_EXTENSION(excel), WORDPAD_EXTENSION(wordpad), EXTENSION2007(ver){}

    //method to ensure base class is abstract
    virtual void Interface() = 0;
};

struct eOfficeExtensions2003 : public eOfficeExtensions{

public:


    eOfficeExtensions2003() : eOfficeExtensions(_T(".doc"), _T(".xls"), _T(".rtf"), 0){}

private:
    virtual void Interface(){}
};

struct eOfficeExtensions2007OrLater : public eOfficeExtensions{


    eOfficeExtensions2007OrLater() : eOfficeExtensions(_T(".docx"), _T(".xlsx"), _T(".rtf"), 1){}

private:
    virtual void Interface(){}
};
```

This feels like a ridiculous amount of code for what should be a simple conditional definition. What would an experienced programmer do?

**EDIT**

These constants should only be set once and never changed. The version of MS Office installed is determined by scanning registry subkeys in a class that deals with memory management.

The constants are mainly used to create new files or search a directory for files with that extension, not for resolving conditional statements. The struct should also be instantiated once as a eOfficeExtensions* pointer to the relevant child struct.

Comment: Should these "constants" change at runtime?
If not, just use simple conditional compilation for their definition

Comment: `What would an experienced programmer do?` Isn't this totally opinion based?

Comment: I don't see any description about how these constants are used.  Are they used to determine "is this a file for the following format"?  Are they widely used?  Would replacing them with a list of extensions make sense?  As an aside, the `virtual void Interface()=0` is a bad idea.  Make the constructor protected if you want to force inheritance.  Please describe what you want to do, what you tried to do, and how it failed.

Comment: These are all great comments. I am editing my question to answer them. I'd also like to point out that I am inexperienced and I understand my question is a bit open-ended, but I'd also like to know what exactly is WRONG with my solution, why it's wrong, and a possible alternative or two (rather than equal yet different opinions on what's the "best" way). Yakk pointing out that I should use "protected" rather than a useless method is exactly the kind of thing I mean. I am guessing I should also define the default and copy constructors as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inheritance tree essentially defines two different values for the base struct.
You don't need inheritance just to define those values, you only need two variables:

```
struct eOfficeExtensions{
    const CString WORD_EXTENSION;
    const CString EXCEL_EXTENSION;
    const CString WORDPAD_EXTENSION;
    const INT EXTENSION2007;
};

const eOfficeExtensions extensions2003{_T(".doc"), _T(".xls"), _T(".rtf"), 0};
const eOfficeExtensions extensions2007{_T(".docx"), _T(".xlsx"), _T(".rtf"), 1};

const eOfficeExtensions* extensions = 0;

// ... Later ...

if (office2007Installed)
    extensions = &extensions2007;
else
    extensions = &extensions2003;
```

Comment: This works and is very elegant! Exactly the kind of modular/expandable thing I was looking for and keeps the struct/const thing from getting too convoluted. Thanks!